# Add to waitbar an elapsed time counter - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the following Matlab GUI code I save a TIFF image and used the waitbar function since it take sometimes few seconds, the bar is not updating and is closing automatically when the file is saved. Is it possible to add an elapsed time counter to indicate time of operation?

code snippet:

```
h = waitbar(0,'In process'); 
export_fig(handles.imageAxes,saveFileAs, '-r500');
close(h);
```

Comment: It is not possible without modifying the function `export_fig` itself. You would have to place the code for `waitbar` (or any other updating/progress report function) **inside** `export_fig.m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer applies [tiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) images specifically.
I tried to find a general solution for `imwrite` function, but I couldn't.

The solution uses **Tiff class** instead of using `imwrite`.
Tiff class allows saving a tiff image file strip by strip, instead of saving entire image at once.
See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html

The following code sample saves a (relatively) large tiff image file, and display an advancing waitbar while saving is in progress:

```
%Simulate large image (to be saved as tiff later)
I = imread('peppers.png');
I = repmat(I, [10, 10]); %Image resolution: 5120 x 3840.

t = Tiff('I.tif', 'w');

width = size(I, 2);
height = size(I, 1);
rows_per_strip = 16; %Select 16 rows per strip.

setTag(t, 'ImageLength', height)
setTag(t, 'ImageWidth', width)
setTag(t, 'Photometric', Tiff.Photometric.RGB)
setTag(t, 'BitsPerSample', 8)
setTag(t, 'SamplesPerPixel', 3)
setTag(t, 'RowsPerStrip', rows_per_strip)
setTag(t, 'PlanarConfiguration', Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky)
setTag(t, 'Compression', Tiff.Compression.LZW)

n_strips = ceil(height / rows_per_strip); %Total number of strips.

h = waitbar(0, 'In process');

%Write the tiff image strip by strip (and advance the waitbar).
for i = 1:n_strips
    y0 = (i-1)*rows_per_strip + 1; %First row of current strip.
    y1 = min(y0 + rows_per_strip - 1, height); %Last row of current strip.
    writeEncodedStrip(t, i, I(y0:y1, :, :)) %Write strip rows y0 to y1.
    waitbar(i/n_strips, h); %Update waitbar.
    drawnow %Force GUI refresh.
end

close(t)
close(h)
```

[image]